# What is "Spawning Pool Party" achievement and how to get it?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

When comparing achievements with a friend, I saw this one under the feats of strength tab. What is this? When will we be able to get it and how do we get it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this post on the official forum](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/9165987080?page=5#93); it appears that the achievement can be unlocked by playing a game with a guest player in your party until completion (no rage-quitting or early leaving or so).

The easiest way to achieve this would be to give one of your *Starcraft 2 Guest Passes* to a friend (or use it yourself to play the game using 2 different PCs).

The achievement is apparently usually awarded at the Experience or Score screen.

**EDIT:**
[image]

Comment: damn! i gave it to my friend just 2-3 weeks ago after i purchased collectors edition hots :( will "any" guest player do?

Comment: The post says `Invite others, who would also receive this achievement, I suppose` so maybe yes? It might be difficult to find random guests, though.

Comment: @Nolonar I added the achievement from in game to your post. Its from CarbotAnimations which is an independent animation studio.

Comment: The achievement should also be awarded after inviting a WoL player to a HotS game.

Comment: @Orc JMR, The achievement is rewarded after the game is finished. Only after a victory or defeat is achieved will the achievement be rewarded.

Comment: @NieselClementine Yup, I meant "inviting and playing through". Emphasis on versions, that it does not require a guest to be Starter, but any "lesser" license.

Answer (score 1):

The achievement is only rewarded by inviting a Wings of Liberty player into your HotS party and completing a game. the Achievement is rewarded only if both players finish the entire game and you will both receive the Achievement at the score screen.

You can do this for any WoL player, and anyone who already has the achievement will still be able to help you get yours.